# Sample with constrain / Randomize with constrain

Tags: r, random

I have the following data frame

```
 design <- read.table(text =
"block position
 1     1
 1     2
 1     3
 1     4
 2     1
 2     2
 2     3
 2     4", header = TRUE)
```

I want to randomly assign four treatments within one block. I could do this for example with the following code:

```
treatment <- letters[1:4]
set.seed(2)
design$treatment <- as.vector(replicate(2,sample(treatment, length(treatment))))
```

resulting in the following data frame

```
> design
 block position treatment
 1        1         a
 1        2         c
 1        3         b
 1        4         d
 2        1         d
 2        2         c
 2        3         a
 2        4         b
```

Problem: in the example above the treatment c is two times at position 2. One treatment should not be two times at the same position. How can I achieve this?

**More general:** Is there an easy solution for sampling with constrain?

Comment: Unless you really need randomness, it's simplest to just lag for each group, e.g. `design$treatment <- unlist(lapply(seq(max(design$block)), function(x){letters[if (x == 1) 1:max(design$position) else c(seq(x, max(design$position)), seq(x - 1))]})) `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following method should ensure (1) randomness of treatments, and (2) non-identical treatments at the same position for different blocks.

1. We calculate all permutations of `letters[1:4]` using `gtools::permutations`. We store the set of permutations in a matrix `perm`.

   ```
   # Calculate all permutations of letters[1:4]
   library(gtools);
   treatment <- letters[1:4];
   perm <- permutations(length(treatment), length(treatment), treatment);
   ```
2. We create an empty `treatment` vector that will be filled successively block by block.

   ```
   design$treatment <- "";
   ```
3. We now randomly draw a permutation from `perm` for the first `block`. Once we have drawn a permutation, we remove all permutations from `perm` (i.e. our set of permutations) that have *any* identical entries at the same positions. We then randomly draw a permutation from the reduced set of permutations for the second `block`. And so on.

   ```
   set.seed(2017);
   for (i in 1:length(unique(design$block))) {
       smpl <- perm[sample(nrow(perm), 1), ];
       design$treatment[seq(1 + 4 * (i - 1), 4 * i)] <- smpl;
       # Remove all permutations with duplicated letters
       j <- 1;
       while (j <= nrow(perm)) {
           if (any(perm[j, ] == smpl)) perm <- perm[-j, ] else j <- j + 1;
       }
   }
   design;
   #    block position treatment
   #1     1        1         d
   #2     1        2         c
   #3     1        3         a
   #4     1        4         b
   #5     2        1         b
   #6     2        2         a
   #7     2        3         d
   #8     2        4         c
   ```

Remove `set.seed(...)` to use a random seed.

Comment: Very nice! Unfortunately, my reprex is largely simplified and my real data have 330 treatments. The calculation of all possible permutations is therefore not an option. I slightly adopted your code so it also works for my project (see answer below). The only difference is, that I calculate only some and not all possible permutations.

Comment: @retodomax Agreed, the number of permutations grows large very quickly with more treatments. I like your approach; the number of initial permutations needs to be large enough to ensure that you can draw enough permutations after successively having removed the ones with duplicated entries. I guess this is a bit of trial-and-error.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for a larger number of treatments and is based on the [answer of Maurits Evers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49372815/6152316). Only 1000 permutations are calculated instead of all possible permutations.

```
n_treat <- 20

# make large design file
design <- data.frame(block = rep(1:4, each = n_treat), position = rep(1:n_treat, 4))

# Calculate some (not all) random permutations
treatment <- 1:n_treat
perm <- t(replicate(1000,sample(treatment, length(treatment), replace = F)))

# Create empty treatment vector
design$treatment <- ""

# loop through all blocks,
# randomly draw a permutation from perm,
# remove permutations with identiacal entries at the same position.
set.seed(2017);
for (i in 1:length(unique(design$block))) {
  smpl <- perm[sample(nrow(perm), 1), ];
  design$treatment[seq(1 + n_treat * (i - 1), n_treat * i)] <- smpl;
  # Remove all permutations with duplicated letters
  j <- 1;
  while (j <= nrow(perm)) {
    if (any(perm[j, ] == smpl)) perm <- perm[-j, ] else j <- j + 1;
  }
}
```